# Не работает getch()

Tags: c++

Такой вопрос: почему при вводе в программу значение (именно не целое) дублируется?
Вот код:

```
void main(void)
{
    int g = 0;
    int flagmin = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int flagpoint = 0;
    double r1 = 0, im1 = 0;
    int x = 0, h = 0;

    cout << "Vvedi a.re: ";
    while (true) {
        fflush(stdin);
        cin << x;
        if (x == 13)
            break;

        switch (x) {

        }

    }
    if (flagmin == 1)
        r1 = r1 * (-1);
    cout << '\n';
    flagmin = 0;
    flagpoint = 0;
    g = 0;
    i = 0;
    cout << "Vvedi a.im: ";
    while (true) {
        cin << x;
        if (h == 13)
            break;

        switch (h) {

        }

        if (i == 6)
            break;
    }
    if (flagmin == 1)
        im1 = im1 * (-1);

    complex a(r1, im1);
    complex b(999, 100);
    complex c = a;        // на сложение
    complex y = a;        // на умножение
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "A:\n";
    a.Print();
    cout << "B:\n";
    b.Print();
    cout << "Symma:\n";
    a = c + b;
    c.Print();
    cout << "Proizv:\n";
    a = y * b;
    y.Print();
    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую привести исходник к нормальному внешнему виду. Плюс, если ты пишешь под линукс, то getch у тебя и не заработает: его там просто нет. Его можно сделать самому.))

[Чем в Linux можно заменить функцию getch()?](http://forum.codenet.ru/threads/29717-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-Linux-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-getch()) Там есть ответ на английском языке - вот он работает.